# Why I can not define expect a ParseException in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit

I need to add expected = ParseException.class to a Junit method but even after adding it to the method the throwing line shows a "Unhandled exception type ParseException" message and I can not run the test.

**Unit Test**

```
import java.text.ParseException;

@Test (expected=ParseException.class)
public void testConvertDate() {
    String date = "Tue 3434 20 23:33:44 EST 2014";
    MyDate mydate = new MyDate();
    Date result = instance.convertDate(date); //this line shows the message
}
```

**Method**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
public Date convertDate(String d) throws ParseException {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark. Make sure the "ParseException" your method is throwing and the "ParseException" your test is expecting are the same

Comment: @Susie they are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the exception is a [checked exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html) and needs to be declared or enclosed ìn a `try/catch` block. Declare it at the method level to allow it to be managed by `JUnit`.

```
@Test (expected=ParseException.class)
public void testConvertDate() throws ParseException {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "convertDate(Date d)" method have to throw the ParseException (Make sure it doesn't catch it...)
Then it will be propagated to your Test method witch is expecting it.

Comment: the method is throwing it.